# Writing function for onTouchListner, when Imageview held for more than 2 seconds?

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener

I am working on a app to unlock a door by sliding an Imageview upwards and holding it for a  a few seconds. I have designed a layout in a ConstraintLayout Layout.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background_color"
android:padding="50dp">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/background_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/switch_button_background" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fill_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="390dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/background_image"

    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/background_image"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/background_image"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/background_image"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.4"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/switch_button_fill_color">

</ImageView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_view"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:clipChildren="true"
    android:gravity="center|bottom"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/fill_image"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/fill_image"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/fill_image"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/fill_image"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumb_icon"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/trimmy"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.48"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.72" />


</LinearLayout>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_unlock"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/fill_image"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/fill_image"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/fill_image"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/fill_image"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.23000002"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_unlock" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/main_login"
    android:layout_width="91dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/background_image"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.7"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/team_xx" />
```

I have tried to handle dragging event by OnThouchListner:

```
thumbIcon.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:                        
                    yDown = event.getY();                        
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    float movedY;
                    movedY = event.getY();
                    float distance = movedY - yDown;
                    float currentDistance = thumbIcon.getY() + distance;
                    
                    if (currentDistance > 450) {
                        return false;
                    } else if (currentDistance < 50) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        thumbIcon.setY(thumbIcon.getY() + distance);
                    }
                    break;
                    
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    undoAnimation();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I added if statements to limit Imageview moving bounds. However since I want to hold the thumb image upwards for a few seconds. I have no idea how to code this task? It would be great if anyone could help me.

**EDIT:**

I have came up with sort of workaround to tackle this issue. Although it's not perfect but it is the only possible solution I could come up with.

```
 switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // ... 
                    countDownTimer.start();
                    break;
```

I have added a countDownTimer to my code. for going off in two seconds. Then I check if the thumb icon or my moveable view is at the right position. then I execute whatever method I want in onFinish() block of my code:

```
countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(2000, 250) {            
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            if (linearLayout.getY() >= thumbIcon.getY()) {
                //Execute my code here...
            }
```

I leave this question unanswered since this approach is not ideal. And this solution was inspired by Henry Twist comment.

Comment: Logically you would just need to schedule a task in a few seconds when they touch and cancel it if they move away or let go.

Comment: I'll suggest to go with `MotionLayout`, make a draggable ImageView ([this](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout/examples#basic) is what you need), attach a listener to it and set your long hold login in `onMotionEnd()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set long click listener to your Linear Layout of your Image View it-self.

```
  thumbIcon.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
               ...
            }
        });
```

Just noticed that your linear layout around your image view is smaller than image view.

Comment: Thanks, but as far as I know it's not possible to set long click and touch listener at the same time for a view.

Answer (score 0):

To hold the thumb image upwards for a few seconds you can start a Long Click Handler with a delay in milliseconds in your **MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN** and you can remove this handler in on **MotionEvent.ACTION_UP**. When the Long Click handler triggered you can set a boolean value eg: **enabledDragging = true** where then in your **MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE** you can use this flag to activate your move logic.
Example of this will be like below:

```
thumbIcon.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                 startLongClickHandler();
                 break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                 if(!enabledDragging)
                   return true;
                 //your move logic .....
                 break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                 removeLongClickHandler();
                 break;
       }
       return true;
     }
 });
```

And the Long Click Handler methods will be like:

```
private boolean enabledDragging = false;
     
private void startLongClickHandler(){
  longClickHandler.postDelayed(mLongPressed, 2000);//2sec
}

private void removeLongClickHandler(){
   longClickHandler.removeCallbacks(mLongPressed);
   enabledDragging = false;
}

private final Handler longClickHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable mLongPressed = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
   enabledDragging = true;
  }
};
```